# Maybe a Really simple, Dynamic Linq To Entities Select statement?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

What I want basically is to be able to to the following (following is psuedo code)

```
string SelectField = cb1.Name.Substring(2);
MyContext.Items.Select(x=>x.SelectField )
```

I tried the following:

```
string SelectField = cb1.Name.Substring(2);
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "p");
var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(pe, SelectField), pe);

query = MyContext.Items.Select(p=>expr)
```

but it gave me the error:

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Is this possible? I just want to be able to select a single entity property based on the selection of my combobox.

Comment: Are there a lot of properties? If no maybe a switch with different queries will be easier.

Comment: Also, dynamic linq library can help you: http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com

Comment: @Gusman that was my though, but ther eare roughly 15 properies, and even if less I would like to know if there is a simplier way the doesn't require duplicated code with only one change

Comment: Take a look to the library in my previous comment, allows to create linq queries from strings.

Comment: @Gusman I'd really like to not import another dependency on a library, looking at the source to it, it looks to use Expression Trees the same way I am trying to use them anyways, maybe it'll help me figure out what I did wrong though.

Comment: Well, as you said, you have the full source code, so you can take it as reference

Comment: At first glance your last line definitely looks wrong. Try using the generic version of Lambda (Expression.Lambda<T>) and just pass expr to the Select method instead of p=>expr.

Comment: @Sacrilege Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my desired results using the following code (not much different then my original attempt)

```
string SelectField = cb1.Name.Substring(2);
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "p");
Expression expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(pe, SelectField), pe);

Expression<Func<Item, string>> expression = (Expression<Func<Item, string>>)expr;

var query = MyContext.Items.Select(expression);
```

All I was missing was the Func line. It now works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with this type of solution you're likely going to have to do a bunch of reflection to get it to work dynamically.

```
string SelectField = cb1.Name.Substring(2);
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "p");
```

First you have to invoke the lambda method without knowing the complete return type. The return type is `Expression<Func<Item, ?>>` (with the question mark being a placeholder for the property type.

```
var propertyType = typeof(Item).GetProperty(SelectField).GetGetMethod().ReturnType;
var lambdaMethodParamType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Item), propertyType);
var lambdaMethod = typeof(Expression).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Lambda" && x.IsGenericMethod).MakeGenericMethod(lambdaMethodParamType);
var expr = lambdaMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { Expression.Property(pe, SelectField), new ParameterExpression[] { pe } });
```

Then we have to invoke the select method in a similar fashion because the property type isn't know until runtime.

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Select").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Item), propertyType);
var query = (IQueryable)selectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { MyContext.Items, expr });
```

I don't know what you're doing with the query variable so I can't provide any further guidance with that at this time. Again, in this example we don't know what type will be contained in the collection until runtime because it is a collection of the property values.

FYI: ***My method for selecting the correct lambda and select was a total hack. You really should create a more robust search method examing the signature more completely to ensure you've found the correct method you are needing. I can provide a better example later if you need it when I have more time.***

Comment: Thank you for your input I was able to accomplish the goal by adding 1 line to my original attempt. See my answer for my final solution. I got to this answer based on your earlier comment and part of your answer. Would using info from your answer allow me to make this generic though?